# Not able to bind Angular select when Bootstrap theme is applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a piece of code which works fine in Angular 1.2 without including Bootstrap, but when I use the `selectpicker` class of Bootstrap the data binding is not happening. Below is the piece of demo code.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
 <body>
  <div ng-controller='Contact'>
    <select class="selectpicker" ng-model='selected_person' ng-options='person.name for person in people'>
    <option value="">Choose option</option>
   </select>
   <br>
      Selected name = {{selected_person.name}}
   </div>
   <br>


   <script>
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

   function Contact($scope){
       $scope.people = [
           {name:"Abc",number: 65},
           {name:"Xyz",number: 75},
           {name:"Pqr",number: 85}
       ];
   }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works even with bootstrap I tries your code.

Comment: i am trying the same code with bootstrap its not populating when i use $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

Comment: This question is already asked on stackoverflow here https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select you need to use angular-bootstrap-select i have given you link.

Answer (score 1):

[image]You don't want to have have some jQuery in a file and some AngularJS in another file, usually. If jQuery creates elements etc, they probably won't be picked up by angular.

The correct solution is to use an Angular directive. Here, it looks like somebody made one for you.

[angular-bootstrap-select](http://joaoneto.github.io/angular-bootstrap-select/)

this is what i got for you, the question asked in stackoverflow the same answer I copied for you see here docs [download here](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select)

Comment: Sorry i am new to angular. So didn't get this thing properly. :(

Comment: your code with bootstrap worked for me see snap. But still if you are unable to get then you need to create directive. as i have given link refer it and modify code.

Comment: Do you know http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ visit this site this has all directive support for angular in bootstrap.

Comment: How did this work for you.? Did you make any change in the code.?

Comment: which bootstrap you are using?? I have latest bootstrap. I dont know from where you included bootstrap-select.css n js.

Comment: I cant find bootstrap-select.css n js. try removing them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59166/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-shavez).

Comment: tried removing didnt work. Please paste the code that you used in sample.html

Comment: My final answer after some research  is if you want to use bootstrap-select with angular then you have to create directive the sample for creating directive you need to download angular-bootstrap-select-master it is available here https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select download and try running demo folder.All the best